# View programatically assigned 'data' value on element in Firefox with Developer Tools?

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox (Version 79) with the built-in Developer Tools, is there a way to inspect an element and see the value of a data attribute programatically applied (e.g using JQuery's `$element.data('name', 'value')` construct)?

**Update** with example;

For Example, if My HTML is like

```
<span id="myElement">This is my element</span>
```

and in my JavaScript, I have done

```
$("#myElement").data("foo", "bar");
```

such that there is no `data-foo` attribute in the HTML, but it is there programmatically, then when viewing in Firefox, if I "Inspect Element", how can I see the value of it?

Comment: You mean something like `element.getAttribute("data-attribute");`?

Comment: No. @imvain2, I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: you can directly run a command in console `$("#myElement").data("foo")` just like you would do in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not see the stored value by inspecting the element. because `$.fn.data` do not stores the information directly on the element (*jQuery sotred the value internaly*) and you can not access the stored value outside of jQuery.

(`$('div.target').data('key', 'value');` do not add `data-key` to the `div` like `<div class='target' data-key='value'>...<div>`. so you can not see the value. you have to get value using code.)

You have 2 options:

1. Don't use `$.fn.data`, use `$.fn.attr` instead.
2. Use `$.fn.data(key)` to access stored value.

For more info see [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7261619/3367974)

*P.S: Do not use `$.fn.data` to add the value and `$.fn.attr` to get value or vice versa, stick with one of them.*

Comment: And the third option; type `$("#myElement").data("foo")` in the console